# How to create a folder programmatically on Android 1.x to 4.x

Tags: android, directory

I want to create from my App a bunch of folders on the Home screen with Apps and Shortcuts inside. I also need to change these folders once in a while, adding and removing items in there.

Android 1.x and 2.x used to have Live Folders that have been deprecated.
Honeycomb has App Widgets Collections.
I believe Android 4.x has a new type of folders.

Which Api should I use to compatible with all version of Android?

I notice how many other Apps use widgets that looks like folders, but adding them to the Home screen is a pain and they are not standard.